# Send money from Braintree

Tags: braintree

I use Braintree for my website on payment. It's OK when receiving money but now I want to transfer money to specific client account (not refunding). Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Einsamer, did you ever find a solution or a WA for this?
I do understand what Shea is saying, though how can services like these ones ever exist in that case:

https://stripe.com/en-se/blog/send-money-to-debit-cards

https://www.sendmoney24.com/card-to-card-transfer.html

Comment: It's been a long time, but I think sending money to debit is bit easier.

Comment: @Orhan if you still looking for a solution, check my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

This is not possible due to Payment Card Industry regulations:

> [I]t is against card association (e.g. Visa, MasterCard) rules for a merchant to transfer funds to a credit card without a pre-existing sale transaction.<sup>[1](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/transactions/refunds-voids-credits#detached-credits)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Since 2018[¹](https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/bringing-world-class-payout-capabilities-to-braintree/), Braintree has integration with Hyperwallet, a payout company aqcuired by PayPal.

https://www.braintreepayments.com/features/payouts

> Diverse payout options
>
> Let your recipients choose how they receive
>   their funds, including direct bank deposit, prepaid card, PayPal, and
>   more.

[Hyperwallet documentation](https://docs.hyperwallet.com/content/hyperwallet-payout-documentation)