# Send money from Braintree account to customers account

Tags: payment, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I 'm stuck with a problem of transferring money from my merchant account to my customers bank account. So I just queried and googled a lot to get a appropriate solution and i just recently met with a comment that

"`Braintree` only help to accept credit card payments from customers."

Is it possible that I can send money from my `braintree` account to my customers bank account once I received in my `braintree` account ?
What can be a better solution for transferring payments to customers bank accounts or credit cards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send money from Braintree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767698/send-money-from-braintree)

Comment: Hi @Shea, Is there any possible way to to transfer money to my customers account. 
If No, What will a better solution you can prefer me in such a situation?

Comment: As stated in the answer to the question I shared, this is not possible and is a violation of Payment Card Industry regulations. I have no recommendations for you.

Answer (score 0):

For the credit card is not advised because the credit card regulation prohibit transfer funds without a previous credit card transaction.

But for bank accounts, prepaid cards, PayPal accounts, etc. see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60834107/2067157